# Copy file(s) within the container in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I copy a file from a path within the container to a different path *within that same container* in a Dockerfile during the docker-compose build process?

```
COPY <src> <dest>
```

This copies a file from the host outside the container. I don't know how to have `<src>` specify a file inside the container to copy.

Comment: Just `RUN` a `cp`?

Comment: How can I use the syntax of cp to achieve that?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I read the official documentation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy but i did not find out how to specify the <src> path so that it is not taken from the host.

What is the syntax for the <src> when I want to specify a path WITHIN the container and not the host?

Comment: @tkausl means you should use `RUN cp ...` rather than `COPY ...`.

Comment: RUN [shell command] execute the shell command. SO "cp" here is the cp command of your beloved linux. To see how cp works, search on the internet how do man cp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @tkausl and @JohnKugelman  pointed out files can be copied by the following command syntax:

```
RUN cp <src-path-within-the-container> <dest-path-within-the-container>
```