# How do I copy files from from the current docker build stage from one directory to another?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How is one meant to copy files that are part of the base image of the current stage in a multistage docker build?

E.g. if I want to start with a base image of alpine 3.7 how would I copy the file `/etc/resolv.conf` to somewhere I wanted it?

---

First version of my Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.7 as dev
WORKDIR /test
COPY /etc/resolv.conf /test
```

```
$ docker build -t foo:bar .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.7 as dev
 ---> 6d1ef012b567
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /test
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a82a71a856b0
Step 3/3 : COPY /etc/resolv.conf /test
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder820934750/etc/resolv.conf: no such file or directory
```

---

Second version of my Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.7 as dev
WORKDIR /test
COPY --from=dev /etc/resolv.conf /test
```

```
$ docker build -t foo:bar .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.7 as dev
 ---> 6d1ef012b567
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /test
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a82a71a856b0
Step 3/3 : COPY --from=dev /etc/resolv.conf /test
invalid from flag value dev: pull access denied for dev, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: Do you have both the `as dev` part on your `FROM` as well as `COPY --from=dev ...` in a later stage? These have to be in the same `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @tadman - not sure I follow (I'm very new to docker). Those three lines I pasted in my "something I tried" and "something else I tried" sections are the _entirety_ of my `Dockerfile`.

Comment: The problem is the first one has only one stage, the second is copying from itself to itself? You need two `FROM` declarations to have a multi-stage build.

Comment: @tadman - Updated my comment; hope what I'm doing is a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you just need to `RUN cp ...` to use the standard Unix `/bin/cp` command?  (See also [Copy file(s) within the container in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058057/copy-files-within-the-container-in-dockerfile).)

Comment: @DavidMaze - that looks like what I need. So is it the case that `COPY` is strictly between distinct stages and `RUN cp ...` is to be used for copying within the same stage?

Comment: `COPY` is from the build context into an image, or from a previous stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a multi-stage build can be tricky to get right, but the basics look like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.7 as dev
WORKDIR /test

# ... Do additional stuff in the "dev" stage

# Define a new stage called whatever you want, here called "final"
FROM alpine:3.7 as final

# Copy from an earlier stage
COPY --from=dev /etc/resolv.conf /test
```

Doing `--from` only makes sense if you are referencing a previous stage. It doesn't do anything useful if you have only one stage. It cannot reference other `Dockerfile` stages directly, you must have a corresponding `FROM ... AS ...` directive.

Comment: I see...so in order to use `COPY` it's _strictly_ necessary to copy between two distinct stages? I.e. `COPY` does not work within the same stage? Is there no way to copy files from src to dest within the same stage?

Comment: You can copy within a stage all you want, but you don't need to use the `--from` option if it's the same stage. That's only for pulling from different stages, specifically those that have run *before* the one you're on.

Comment: Wasn't my first attempt copying without using the "--from" option? And if so, why did that fail?

Comment: The first argument to `COPY` is presumed to be relative to `Dockerfile`, not the container. To copy within the container consider using `RUN cp ...`

Comment: It's worth checking the [documentation for `COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) and keeping that page open while you work through any `Dockerfile`. These things are subtly tricky.